# Setting php environment variable on windows with vagrant

Tags: php, windows, laravel, vagrant, laravel-artisan

i'm trying to run "php artisan" comands on Windows, but the system returns an error that php variable path isn't set.
The problem is that i don't have php installed directly on the Windows system, but it is installed on the vagrant box.
Any ideas how to set the windows php environment variable to the vagrant boxe's php?

thanks

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to run this on the command line in the Vagrant box?

Comment: You need to ssh first.  `vagrant up` then `vagrant ssh`

Comment: Thanks,

I'm not sure how to run it directly on vagrant, so i'm trying to run it from the windows powershell, which returns an error, is there an other way to do it?

I'm already using the vagrant up command before the "php artisan"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Vagrant, you need to set all variables there. To do this, you need to use SSH. You can try built-in `vagrant ssh` command or any SSH client for Windows (WinSCP for example, connect and then press Ctrl+T for WinSCP Terminal).

Default credentials for vagrant ssh are:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
Login: vagrant
Password: vagrant
Port: 2222
```